# Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field

Tags: custom-object, deployment, sharing, master-detail

I am trying to deploy an update to a custom object. The object and classes associated with it work perfectly in my sandbox, but when I try to deploy, I get the following error:

```
Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field
```

The object has two fields of Master-Detail type, one is Contact, which I left default sharing and one is another custom object which I set to Read Only.

On the object itself I unchecked sharing in the hope that would help.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do here?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you included all of your object's fields in your deployment, or just the object itself?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a recent issue with Salesforce. To workaround this issue, please add the master detail field (even if it has not been changed) to your deployment and the error will go away.

I have already filed a Case with Salesforce and they are working on it.

[Salesforce knowledge article link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232550&type=1)

Comment: Can you please provide a link to that Case?

Comment: I also would like the link, or if you have posted to the Salesforce Community website. Its 2016 and this issue hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Seems I still get this issue... any update on it yet? please.

Comment: But what do you do when you cannot see the object on the list, to be added to the changeset

Comment: It's 2020 and I'm still getting this error - now with scratch orgs too! :)

Comment: I do no t even have MD relationship between objects; do not know how this conflict happened from local scratch org to salesforce org

Comment: Almost 2023 and still having this issue with scratch orgs. Specifically trying to build a package version where a custom object has a master-detail relationship with the account object.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. First I deployed the custom object without the fields and hence the deployment failed. Then I came across this post, did not understand it well, but I assumed to add the custom fields of the custom object in the change set as well as the custom object and it worked.

**So we need :**

1. The custom object to be added to the change set
2. The custom fields of that custom object to be added as well to the change set.

I just don't know why salesforce are separating the custom fields from the custom object. Thans sridhar for the hint