# How to transfer Master-Detail to Lookup conversion from sandbox to production in a change-set?

Tags: deployment, lookup, sandbox, master-detail, change-set

The message I get is similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50354/cannot-set-sharingmodel-to-controlledbyparent-on-a-customobject-without-a-master).
I have a Master-Detail relationship(M-D) in Sandbox and production. I need to change M-D to Lookup in Production. I changed in sandbox, then added field to change-set. When I try to get it in production, it throws below error.

```
Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field.
```

Am I doing this wrong? or do we have a workaround for this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sharing model does not match the criteria for a lookup.

Please try to update your sharing model for the object you are changing the md to lookup before you deploy. For example change it to private or similar...

Comment: Thank you @Jannis Bott. It shows up in sharing settings. But when I click it for editing, it disappears. Wonder how should I proceed editing this.

Comment: Apologies for the delay @Pasan Eeriyagama. The easiest way to change this is rather then deploying the field, to make this a manual change. If you go to your object in production --> click on your field --> click edit --> you can make the change from master-detail to lookup

Comment: Thanks @Jannis Bott. That's the way I achieved it which I think is a workaround but not the way it supposed to be as we have change-sets to manage developments.